# Slicing lists and strings to negative zero

Tags: python

I've read the [Python informal tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) on slicing, which all makes sense to me except for one edge case. It seems like

```
'help'[:-0]
```

should evaluate to `'help'`, but it really evaluates to `''`. What's a good way to think about negative index slicing so that this particular edge case makes sense?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`'help'[:-0]` is actually equal to `'help'[:0]`, in which case it makes sense that it evaluates to `''`. In fact, as you can see from the interactive python interpreter, `-0` is the same as `0`:

```
>>> -0
0
```

Comment: That's not an "assume".  You assumed very little.  You actually ran actual code and actually proved what the actual result is.  Drop the "assume" business from this otherwise good answer.

Answer (score 3):

`-0 == 0`, so `'help'[:-0]` is equivalent to `'help'[0:0]`, which I think you will agree should be `''`.

The following question has some good general info on slices and how to think of them: [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation)

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, `-0 == 0` therefore the output `''` makes complete sense.

In case you want a consistent behaviour when using negative indices, you could use `len()` in the slicing index:

```
>>> a = 'help'
>>> a[:len(a)-0]
'help'
```

Comment: Indeed, `-0 == 0`. Welcome to SO !

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said, `-0 == 0`, in which case the `''` result is correct. I think you're looking for:

```
'help'[:]
```

When slicing, if you omit the start it starts from 0, if you omit the end, it advances until the end of the collection (in your case a string). Thus, `[:]` means *"beginning to end"*.